# Google sheets query functions: how to do arithmetic on columns with non-constants, i.e. dividing not by a constant but by another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, arithmetic-expressions

I understand how to do arithmetic on a column using a query function as long as I'm using a fixed constant. However, if I try to do the same using a cell reference instead of a constant, I get an error.

I've tried making the cell a named range and referring to that name hoping it would act like a constant but I still get errors. There must be a way to do this. Here are examples of things that work:

`=QUERY(FebMarket,"SELECT (C/5)")`    //This divides column C by 5

`=QUERY(FebMarket,"SELECT AVG(C)")`   //This gives me the average of column C

`=QUERY(FebMarket,"SELECT AVG(C) LABEL AVG(C) ''")`
                                    //average of col C without a header

However, if I do any of the following I get an error:

`=QUERY(FebMarket,"SELECT C/(AVG(C) LABEL AVG(C) '')")`

`=QUERY(FebMarket,"SELECT C/(AVG(C))")`

`=QUERY(FebMarket,"SELECT C/AVG(C)")`

`=QUERY(FebMarket,"SELECT C/avgC")`   // where 'avgC' is a named range given to a cell where I calculated the average of column C separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(C1:C,
 "select C / "&AVERAGE(C1:C), 0), 
 "select Col1 
  where Col1 is not null
  label Col1 '' ", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! Awesome. Thank you. I am going to have to spend time figuring out some of the techniques you used, but thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, if you don't mind, could I ask you what the 0 signifies in the outer and inner query?

Comment: zero is for header rows - just in case, because sometimes query cant recognise dataset and wrongly assumes that there is header row even if there isnt

Comment: Nice - this is probably the nearest you can get to a subquery in a Google Sheets query.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you get the same result in all dialects of SQL. You can do one of two things in a single query:

```
Get the result of an aggregate (like AVGE) over the entire dataset
```

e.g.

```
=QUERY(FebMarket,"SELECT AVG(C)")
```

in which case you can only select aggregates in the query

or

```
Get an aggregate for each one of a set of groups defined by one or more grouping variables.
```

e.g.

```
=QUERY(FebMarket,"SELECT GroupVariable,AVG(C) group by groupVariable")
```

in which case you can select grouping variables and aggregates in the query.

Neither of these help.

If you google something like 'SQL divide column by its average' you will probably get an answer  using a subquery but at time of writing these are not available in Google Sheets.

So (although you could do this shorter by other means) the solution using queries would have to be

```
=ArrayFormula(query(A:A,"select A where A is not null")/query(A:A,"select avg(A) label avg(A) ''"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I will have to take some time to understand your technique. Interestingly someone provided a slightly different method which also worked. The only problem I had with your method is it gave me an error in the top cell which contained my header. However all of the averages were present and correct. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes you are right, the header row will give an error. You could fix it with =ArrayFormula(iferror(query(A:A,"select A where A is not null")/query(A:A,"select avg(A) label avg(A) ''"),A1)) but not very elegant.

Comment: Or =ArrayFormula(query(A:A,"select A where A is not null",0)/query(A:A,"select avg(A) label avg(A) ''")) and put the header in manually etc.